# Why is react context not updating?

Tags: reactjs

I have never had a problem with contexts not updating, does anyone please have any idea why I cannot see the new string? I did add the Provider as a parent of Child.

Logs:

```
state
effect
effect
state
setState
```

code

```
export const MyContext = React.createContext();

export default function MyContextProvider({ children }) {
  const [state, setState] = useState('');
  console.log('state', state);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('effect', state);
  }, [state]);

  //Other logic requiring state

  return <MyContext.Provider value={{ state, setState }}>{children}</MyContext.Provider>;
}
```

```
export default function Child() {
    const { state, setState } = useContext(MyContext);

    useEffect(() => {
      //Trying to force update
    }, [state, setState]);

    return (
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          console.log('setState');
          setState('testing');
        }}
      >
        Save
        {state} {/* Trying to force update */}
      </button>
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you post a sandbox link? There's nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: yeah its really confusing, i have about 20 contexts and all work fine except this one, also works fine in codesandox

Comment: Maybe look for naming collision in your wapper/provider, since you have so many contexts

Comment: thanks but no its very different